# Перевод строк в числа в bash-e

Tags: bash

```
countlines=0
cat file.txt | while read line
do
   countlines=$countlines+1     
   echo $line
done
count=0
number1=0
number2=0
cat file.txt | while read line
do
   count=$count+1
   if [$count -eq $countlines-1]; then                          
     number1=$line      
   if [$count -eq $countlines-2]; then                          
     number2=$line         
   echo $line
done
```

Этот код читает две последние строки из файла, для которых наперед известно, что они являются числами. Вопрос состоит в том содержат ли переменные number1 и number2 числовые или текстовые значения, если они содержат текстовые значения, то как их перевести в числовые? Строка number2 впоследствии будет использоваться в цикле for (значение количества итераций), каким образом сделать так, чтобы number2 в цикле for было воспринято как число?

Comment: Это bash? И кто Вам сказал, что этот код именно это делает?

Comment: а что он по вашему делает?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Хотелось бы знать. При попытке выполнить получил ругань bash'а

Comment: > countlines=$countlines+1

Этот код не будет работать. Для выполнения арифметических операций нужно использовать конструкцию:

    countlines=$[$countlines + 1]

> Вопрос состоит в том содержат ли переменные number1 и number2 числовые или текстовые значения, если они содержат текстовые значения, то как их перевести в числовые?

Что такое текстовые значения? Bash оперирует исключительно текстовыми данными, в нем нету ни числовых, ни каких-либо других типов.

Comment: Строка number2 впоследствии будет использоваться в цикле for (значение количества итераций), каким образом сделать так, чтобы number2 в цикле for было воспринято как число?

Answer (score 2):

```
# количество строк в файле
lines=$(cat file.txt| wc -l);
# чтение предпоследней и последней строк с заменой на числа в начале строки
number1=$(sed -nr "$[$lines - 1]s/^([0-9]*).*$/\1/p" file.txt)
number2=$(sed -nr "$[$lines - 2]s/^([0-9]*).*$/\1/p" file.txt)
```

Либо так:

```
# чтение последней строки
number1=$(sed -nr '$s/^([0-9]+).*$/\1/p' file.txt)
# чтение предпоследней строки
number2=$(sed -nr '$!h;${x;s/^([0-9]+).*$/\1/p}' file.txt)
```

Comment: Просто любопытства ради, зачем `cat file.txt | wc -l`, а не `wc -l file.txt`? Количество процессов надо нарастить?

Comment: @alexlz, что-бы не парсить число строк. Иначе пришлось-бы делать как-то так:

    res=($(wc -l file.txt));
    lines=${res[0]}

Comment: Виноват. Не подумал. `wc -l <file.txt`

Comment: Да, вариант.

Answer (score 1):

код можно несколько упростить:

```
count=0
tail -n 2 file.txt | while read line
do
count=$count+1
if [ $line -eq $line 2> /dev/null ]; then
echo "$line $count is a number"
else
echo "$line $count isn't a number"
fi
done
```

Comment: а что значит условие [ $line -eq $line 2> /dev/null ];?

Comment: Проверка на то, что в переменной line находится число. Операция -eq команд test и [ -- арифметическое сравнение. Если там число, то результат -- истина, оно себе равно. Если нет -- ошибка, о которой bash завопит в stderr. Чтобы он вопил тихо, используется перенаправление stderr (fd == 2) в /dev/null, т.е. в чёрную дыру. Но результат при этом будет "ложь"

Comment: Я считаю, что проверять таким образом число - это моветон. Уж лучше регуляркой:

    if [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        # is numerical
    fi

Comment: Ну регулярка там появилась относительно (если сравнивать с возрастом bash) недавно, и в документации написано, что в конкретной сборке может отсутствовать. 

Лично мне фокусы с ошибками, посылаемыми в дыру (чёрную), тоже не очень симпатичны.